# Maximum charge of a separate capacitor plate

Tags: charge, capacitance, coulombs-law

Suppose we have an initially charged parallel plate capacitor, then we separate the plates so each plate has a positive and negative charge (I did an experiment, the plates hold the charge), I think that if the plates separately have a sufficiently high charge it could explode I am right? If that is the case, how can I calculate the maximum charge that each plate would support before exploding?

Comment: What makes you think it will explode?

Comment: @BobD Coulomb electrostatic repulsion force

Comment: If the charges on each plate are equal and opposite, its an electrostatic attraction force, its it  not? Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @BobD yes, the charges on each plate are opposite but are separated a great distance in such a way that they do not interact, then each plate has a non-zero net charge

Comment: Something is not adding up here for me. You start with with a charged capacitor with net plus and minus charge on each plate of $Q$ and separation $d$. You now further separate the plates to increase $d$. How and why would this result in an explosion?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum charge will depend on the material separating the plates and other parameters. If there is nothing between them but air or a vacuum then that will determine the maximum charge. The capacitance of parallel plates is given by: $$C =  \frac{k \epsilon_0 A}{d}$$ where k is the relative permittivity of the material between the plates. So the maximum charge will depend on the area of the plates A, the distance between them, d, and the material between the plates. There are tables of the relative permittivity for different materials.

When you say explode the only explosion will be due to when the plates arc. The plates may get more charge than the capacitance allows and they will arc between the two plates. That occurs when charge is greater than the maximum charge.